Did the Israelites defecate when eating the manna?
In Exodus 16:1-36, we read that the people of Israel ate the bread from heaven which they gathered from the ground  after the dew of the morning.
Because this material originated from HaShem in heaven, one could figure it must have been without impurity and therefore extremely healthy for the body.
The Israelites ate quail also, but did the consumption of manna result in any unusual effects on the body such as little to no waste production leading to defecation?

Unused muscles atrophy, stop working, with serious health consequences. Look at the problem of astronauts who spend long months in space: sensorimotor coordination disorders, cardiovascular deconditioning, muscular atrophy, bone loss, and anemia/immunodeficiency. For a healthy body, all of your systems must be exercised.

Talmud Bavli Yoma 75b assumes that the manna was entirely absorbed in the body, so that indeed the Israelites did not defecate:

״ועתה נפשנו יבשה אין כל״. אמרו: עתיד מן זה שתיפח במעיהם, כלום יש ילוד אשה שמכניס ואינו מוציא? וכשנאמרו דברים לפני רבי ישמעאל, אמר להם: אל תקרי ״אבירים״, אלא ״איברים״ — דבר שנבלע במאתים וארבעים ושמונה איברים.‏
“But now our soul is dry, there is nothing at all; we have nothing beside this manna to look to” (Numbers 11:6). They said: This manna will eventually swell in our stomachs and kill us; is there anyone born of a woman who ingests food but does not expel waste?
When these words were said before Rabbi Yishmael, he said to them: Do not read it as abirim. Rather, read it as eivarim, limbs. The manna was something that was absorbed by 248 limbs.


Rashi ('Avoda Zara 5b, s.v. "בלחם הקלוקל" and Numbers 21:5) also sees this implied in the description of the manna in Numbers 21:5. Rashi seems to imply (although he doesn't spell it out completely) that the quadriliteral reduplication is an intensive form of the root of קל ("weak"), such that the verse means something akin to, "And our soul reviles this truly insubstantial bread" (truly insubstantial in that it is completely absorbed in the body). Quadriliteral reduplications in Tanach often function as intensives.

The complaint of the complainers was irrational since the manna was indeed nutritious and tasty (Exodus 16:31), so it must mean that the manna was insubstantial in some trivial sense. Thus, Rashi correlates Numbers 21:5 with the interpretation of Psalm 78:24-25 (אברים = אבירים) given by Rabbi Yishmael and the explanation of the hapax (see Rashi there, "ואין דומה לו במקרא") "מחספס" in Exod. 16:14 given by Rabbi Yochanan (identifying it as a gematriatic signifier equal to the traditionally recognized number of "limbs").

But based on the instruction of וְיָד֙ תִּהְיֶ֣ה לְךָ֔ מִח֖וּץ לַֽמַּחֲנֶ֑ה וְיָצָ֥אתָ שָּׁ֖מָּה חֽוּץ, how does one reconcile this?

@Shmuel Rashi ('Avoda Zara 5b, s.v. בלחם הקלוקל) implies that indeed when the Jews ate only the manna, the manna obviated the need for this: "והיא היתה להם טובה גדולה שלא היו צריכין לטרוח ולצאת שלש פרסאות לפנות דתניא (ברכות דף ס) כשהן נפנין אין נפנין לא לצידיהן ולא לפניהן אלא לאחריהן ומחנה ישראל ג' פרסאות היה".

@Shmuel Look up the broader sugya there in Yoma, it deals with that question.

Thanks Fred and Joel K! Will look into it :)

Although this is not exactly the same thing, it is a similar effect observable even today. When one goes on an extended water fast, beyond about 10 days, the  metabolism switches to a state of ketosis, consuming stored body fat. Defacation stops and depending upon the volume of water consumed, urination volume is greatly reduced. The sense of taste becomes extremely acute. Mental acuity is also increased dramatically and eventually sleep becomes reduced. Water fasting beyond 90 days is an intensely spiritual experience worth trying at least once.

In Yoma 75b it says that the manna was completely absorbed. The Rashi on it says it didn't leave their intestines (they didn't defecate).
In Bamidbar Rabba 16:24 it says:

אָמַר לָהֶם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, בַּטּוֹבָה שֶׁהֵבֵאתִי עֲלֵיכֶם בָּהּ אַתֶּם מַכְעִיסִין, בָּאוּ לַמִּדְבָּר וְהֶאֱכַלְתִּי לָהֶם מָן אַרְבָּעִים שָׁנָה, וְלֹא נִצְרַךְ אֶחָד מֵהֶם לִנְקָבָיו אוֹתָן אַרְבָּעִים שָׁנָה, אֶלָּא שֶׁאָכְלוּ אֶת הַמָּן וְהוּא נַעֲשָׂה לָהֶם בָּשָׂר
The Holy One blessed be He said to them: ‘With the benefit that I brought upon you, with that, you infuriate. They came to the wilderness and I fed them manna for forty years, and not one of them needed to relieve himself for those forty years. Rather, they ate the manna and it became flesh for them.

